# C++ from Class to Template

Tags: c++, templates, vector, std

EDIT: Indeed `(*it)->print()` works. Sorry for misleading information. When I wrote the question I thought I tried all posibilities. And the last one, even if I wouldn't have tried it, it seemed wrong to me - pointer to pointer..

Thank you for your time, was a newbie mistake, but it made me see the light!

I've started a little project a week ago. Every worked smoothly untill I had this piece of code, where `this->_items` is `std::vector<CItem*> _items;`

```
std::vector<CItem*>::iterator it;
for ( it = this->_items.begin(); it != this->_items.end(); ++it)
{
    //MUST use .print() for each Item.
    //so:
    //it->print() - nope
    //(*it).print() -nope - same thing.. STILL!!! What's the problem?
    //it.print() - maybe?
    //(*it)->print() - come onn!!
}
```

Ok.. so It didn't work. After doing some research for std::vector I realised yeah, that's a template. Let's do a template. And I kind of did. Header and implementation in one big file,  everywhere.. but the project started breaking.

After did translate Class to Template it didn't work either. So I started adding `template <typename T>` everywhere untill the red line goes away. It does not.

Here are the changes I've done: https://github.com/screws0ft/ubisoft/commit/1b2bd6f9d5d66fcc9315f7a03cc71a2d6f64d57e

So where's the problem? Could someone help me out?

Appreciate it!

Comment: (*it)->print() should be good

Comment: I can't load your link. Can you post the code at the end of your question?

Comment: You don't need to create a template to use a template class like `std::vector<CItem*>`.

Comment: Indeed that last one should have worked. See [this](http://ideone.com/d33end). You never said what the error was though?

Comment: Also, what is the error you got for `(*it)->print()`? As many already mentioned, that should work. Is it possible that `CItem` is incomplete here? I mean you have a forward declaration for it, but you do not `#include` the header file that contains its definition?

Comment: (*it)->print() should have worked. Why did it not? Was there a compiler error? A linker error? No error but incorrect output? No error but a crash?

Comment: Plus, you wrote you made everything a template just because `vector` is a template. You have a misconception, as @aschepler pointed out. This was absolutely unnecessary. Probably, when moving all the member function definitions from the .cpp file to the header file, you forgot to add some `#include` directives and now `CItem` is an incomplete type, so trying to invoke methods on it will generate a compilation error. But the syntax `(*it)->print()` is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However `(*it)->print()` should work.

But, you can do it indirectly too:

```
std::vector<CItem*>::iterator it;
for ( it = this->_items.begin(); it != this->_items.end(); ++it)
{
    CItem *item = *it;
    item->print();
}
```

If none of those don't work. You have a problem in somewhere else. Did you allocated `CItem` objects correctly? ...

Comment: How can this differ from `(*it)->print()`?

Comment: @AndyProwl: It's just a suggestion. I think `(*it)->print()` should work, same as you mentioned.

Comment: OP explicitly says that *this did not work*. This is therefore *not* an answer to the question.

Comment: But *why* did it not work? Was there a compile error? A link error? No error but incorrect output?

Comment: @us2012: My answer is not in his attempted ways. I completely agree with you. I sure it is not a syntax problem. He must missed something else.

Comment: @MM. Since your answer is accepted, you could probably complete it with *why*  it works, because clearly the OP doesn't know about iterator dereferencing.

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty way:

```
for (auto &p : _items)
    p->print();
```

The correct way: change your `print` to something like:

```
std::ostream &print(std::ostream &os) { 
    // print self onto os
    return os;
}
```

Then define an `operator<<` something like:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, item const &i) { 
    return i->print(os);
}
```

...and finally do the printing with something like:

```
std::copy(begin(items), end(items), std::ostream_iterator<item>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Oh, and as shown above, you really want to use `items` (or perhaps `items_`) instead of `_items`. Technically, `_items` is allowable in this context, but I'd generally advise against defining any name with a leading underscore, since the context in which you're allowed to do so is somewhat constrained.

Edit: a short demo of the quick and dirty version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class item { 
    int i;
public:
    std::ostream &print(std::ostream &os) {
        return os << i;
    }

    item(int i) : i(i) {}
};

class whatever { 
    std::vector<item *> items;
public:
    void print_all() { 
        for (auto &i : items)
            i->print(std::cout);
    }

    whatever() { 
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
            items.push_back(new item(i));
    }
};

int main() { 
    whatever w;

    w.print_all();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a beautiful piece of coding, but does not answer the question. And I doubt just rewriting his loop this way would solve his problem. The root cause must be somewhere else

Comment: @AndyProwl I think this does indeed solve the problem. Look at the github source that OP posted, the method called `print` does in fact not print anything but only returns a `string`. If you then call `(*it)->print();` , well, nothing visible happens. Jerry's solution fixes this.

Comment: @us2012: Unfortunately I can't open that link, I don't know why

Comment: @us2012: Wait a second: you mean that the OP was not complaining about any compilation or linking error? That was my assumption somehow. If that's the case then I will upvote this answer.

Comment: @AndyProwl until he tells us what's wrong, we have no way of knowing. I suspect that what he menas by "doesn't work" in the last case is that there's simply no output...

Comment: @us2012: Makes sense. Let's wait

Comment: @AndyProwl: I took it as something like: "don't tell me that I have to use syntax like `(*it)->print();` to invoke the `print()` member for every item (whose address is) in my array. His comments show a number of different attempts for the right syntax...